# como traer el nombre del value y no el id

Tags: php, java, html, sql, ajax

TENGO el siguiente codigo que me trae unos selects anidados de una consulta que le hago a la bd pero al momento de enviar me trae los id y no el campo nombre como tal que es el que necesito que me traiga

```html
     <select class="controls fuentetexto" name="Ciudad" id="sel_ciudad" style="width:100%">
                                                  
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <p    style="color: black; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px " class=" fuentetexto">Selecciona la Tienda</p>
                            <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="sel_tienda"  style="width:100%">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
<br>
<br>

                            <select class="controls " type="Text" name="sel_correopv" id="sel_correopv"  style="width:100%">
                            </select>
```

**lo tengo con modelo visa controlador de la siguiente manera**

Cotrolador

```php
    require '../modelo/modelo_facelectronica.php';
$MF = new modelo_facelectronica();
$consulta = $MF->listar_combo_ciudad();
echo json_encode($consulta);´

require '../modelo/modelo_facelectronica.php';
$MF = new modelo_facelectronica();
$idtienda = $_POST['idtienda'];
$consulta = $MF->listar_combo_correopv($idtienda);
echo json_encode($consulta);

require '../modelo/modelo_facelectronica.php';
$MF = new modelo_facelectronica();
$idciudad = $_POST['idciudad'];
$consulta = $MF->listar_combo_tienda($idciudad);
echo json_encode($consulta);
```

js

```js
function listar_ciudad(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controlador/controlador_listar_ciudad.php',
        type:'POST'
    }).done(function(resp){
        
        var data = JSON.parse(resp);
        var cadena="";
        if(data.length>0){
            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                cadena +="<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#sel_ciudad").html(cadena);
            var idciudad = $("#sel_ciudad").val();
            listar_tienda(idciudad);
        }else{
            cadena +="<option value=''>'NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS'</option>";
            $("#sel_ciudad").html(cadena);
        }
    })
}


function listar_tienda(idciudad){
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controlador/controlador_listar_tienda.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            idciudad:idciudad
        }
    }).done(function(resp){
       
        
        var data = JSON.parse(resp);
        var cadena="";
        if(data.length>0){
            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                cadena +="<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#sel_tienda").html(cadena);
            var idtienda = $("#sel_tienda").val();
            listar_correopv(idtienda);
        }else{
            cadena +="<option value=''>'NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS'</option>";
            $("#sel_tienda").html(cadena);
        }
    })

    
}

function listar_correopv(idtienda){
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controlador/controlador_listar_correopv.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            idtienda:idtienda
        }
    }).done(function(resp){
      
        var data = JSON.parse(resp);
        var cadena="";
        if(data.length>0){
            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                cadena +="<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#sel_correopv").html(cadena);
        }else{
            cadena +="<option value=''>'NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS'</option>";
            $("#sel_correopv").html(cadena);
        }
    })
    document.getElementById('Enviar').onclick = function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("sel_correopv");
        var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        
    }
    
}
```

**modelo que use ** En este cree procedimientos almacenados para que los traiga a la vista de los selects

```php
class modelo_facelectronica{
    private $conexion;
    function __construct(){
        require_once 'modelo_conexion.php';
        $this->conexion = new conexion();
        $this->conexion->conectar();
    } 



    function listar_combo_ciudad(){
        $sql = "call SP_LISTAR_COMBO_CIUDADES";
        $arreglo = array();
        if ($consulta = $this->conexion-> conexion->query($sql)){
            while ($consulta_V = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                $arreglo[]= $consulta_V;
            }
                return $arreglo;
                $this->conexion->cerrar();
            
        }
    }


    function listar_combo_tienda($idciudad){
        $sql = "call SP_LISTAR_COMBO_TIENDAS('$idciudad')";
        $arreglo = array();
        if ($consulta = $this->conexion-> conexion->query($sql)){
            while ($consulta_V = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                $arreglo[]= $consulta_V;
            }
                return $arreglo;
                $this->conexion->cerrar();
            
        }
    }

    function listar_combo_correopv($idtienda){
        $sql = "call SP_LISTAR_COMBO_CORREOPV('$idtienda')";
        $arreglo = array();
        if ($consulta = $this->conexion-> conexion->query($sql)){
            while ($consulta_V = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                $arreglo[]= $consulta_V;
            }
                return $arreglo;
                $this->conexion->cerrar();
            
        }
    }
}
```

ya probe de varias maneras y no logro que al enviar el formulario me capture el dato con el nombre y no con el id que le tengo asignado en la tabla

Comment: No está demás recordar que **Java != JavaScript**.

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Dónde ocurre el problema exactamente? ¿Cuando hablas de *traer* aclara un poco a qué te refieres, traer de dónde, traer haciendo qué tipo de acción, etc? Sospecho que quizá en los `for` no estás poniendo el orden correcto y por eso los elementos no se llenan con el contenido que esperas.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Estrictamente hablando "cómo traer el value y no el id" se responde con: "tienes que seleccionar el value y no el id cuando consultes los datos". Creo que has incluído mucho código (lo que está bien), que no es relevante para tu pregunta (lo que **no** está bien). Por favor indica cuáles son las partes relevantes, elimina lo irrelevante, y trata de enunciar la pregunta de manera que sea útil para la comunidad.

Comment: Hola, totalmente de acuerdo con Arriel, además no pones el código de los SPs que son los que te devuelven los datos